# Resolve Promise in jest from setState Callback

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I want my jest + enzyme unit test  that the `saveSignUpFirstCreds` get called:

```
this.setState({ requestInProgress: true, errorMessage: null }, () => {
  return Api.registerPhone(values.phone)
    .then(() => {
      this.props.saveSignUpFirstCreds(values);
      this.handleSubmitSuccess();
    })
});
```

I have a jest manual mock for my api and my code looks so far like this:

```
wrapper.setState({ requestInProgress: true, errorMessage: null }, () => {
   // DO i need to do something here ???
// I need the promise to be fullfilled and then check the prop and then call done
});
```

in short " how to jest test promise inside setState callback"

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you will have to stub the setState function of your component, and test if the callback is triggered.

```
//component.js

onSubmit() {
  this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1},
  this.props.onSubmitCallback()
)}


//test.js 

const setState = sinon.stub(SomeComponent.prototype, ‘setState’)
          .callsFake( (newState, callback) => { callback() });
const onSubmitCallback = sinon.spy();
const component =
      shallow(<SomeComponent onSubmitCallback={onSubmitCallback}/>);
component.instance().onSubmit();
expect(setState).to.be.calledOnce; //PASS!
expect(onSubmitCallback).to.be.calledOnce; //PASS!
```

As described in this article - https://medium.com/@tjhubert/react-js-testing-setstates-callback-907df1fe720d

Answer (score 0):

```
return expect(saveSignUpFirstCreds(value)).resolves.toEqual('Something');
```

should do the trick.
More info here https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html , and here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Comment: Hi, not really in that way. I want to spy on `saveSignUpFirstCreds` prop method being called. its not a Promise



`this.setState({foo: 'bar'}, () => { 
    // Do something async here. and call saveSignUpFirstCreds
});
`